# Duplicate Checkbox in Page-Object is not defined?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

I am trying to click a checkbox that enables a purchase button to appear. When I try to use it, I get a "NoMethodError: undefined method 'eula' for Cart:0x101f54810" error. I think it may be because there are two identical checkboxes, but I am just not certain.

HTML:

```
<p id="eula-box" class="annoy cc"><input type="checkbox" name="terms_of_service" value="terms_of_service" tabindex=20 />I have read & agree to the End-User License Agreement.</p>
<p id="eula-box" class="annoy pp"><input type="checkbox" name="terms_of_service" value="terms_of_service" tabindex=20 />I have read & agree to the End-User License Agreement.</p>
```

My class:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'page-object'
require 'page-object/page_factory'
require 'watir-webdriver'

CART_URL = 'http://www.anonymizer.com/cart/checkout.html?SKU=ANONUNV12'

class Cart
        include PageObject
        page_url CART_URL
        checkbox(:eula, :class=>"annoy_cc")
        button(:purchase, :value=>'purchase') 

        def complete_order(data = {})
            self.eula.click
        end
end
```

Udpated: I was changing the object type around trying to get it to work. Element was the last type I tried. I changed my example back to checkbox (my original attempt). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Do they really have the same ID? That's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PageObject's `checkbox` generate the following method to check (i.e. click) it.

```
check_eula
```

See http://rubydoc.info/gems/page-object/0.6.3/PageObject/Accessors:checkbox

Comment: RTFM!? I would feel shame except that it's such a big unexpected turn from what I expected.

Answer (score 3):

When you call the class level `checkbox` method in page-object it generates five methods.  The call:

```
checkbox(:summary, :id => 'valid_checkbox')
```

will generate:

```
check_summary     # check the checkbox
uncheck_summary   # uncheck the checkbox
summary_checked?  # returns true if it is checked.  otherwise false
summary_element   # returns the Checkbox object
summary?          # returns true if the element exists.  otherwise false
```

These are the method to interact with when using the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with page-objects, but is `element` a valid accessor?  I'm looking at [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors) and don't see it.  Perhaps it would be better to use the `checkbox` accessor?

As an aside, the easiest way to see if your problem is caused by having two similar checkboxes, would be to just remove one and see if the problem goes away!